# Дублирование и удаление блоков

Tags: javascript

У меня есть блок , при нажатии на кнопку "+" должен прибавиться  точно такой же блок(без заполненных полей. Внутри блока есть кнопка "-" , и она должна именно тот блок, внутри какого она была нажата. Все что получилось, ниже.

```
<div class="k-portlet__body" id='partners_block'>
            <div class='partners' id='duplicater'>
                <div class=" row">
                    <label >Имя</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label >Загрузка фото</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
                        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                            <input type="file"class="form-control">
                        </form> 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <button class="btn  " id="brand_minus">
                        <span> <i class="la la-minus"></i> <span>-</span> </span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>      
        </div>
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <button class=" but-plus" id="brand_plus">
                    <span> <i class="la la-plus"></i> <span>+</span> </span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('brand_plus').addEventListener('click', () => {
var original = document.getElementById('duplicater');
let counts= document.getElementsByClassName('partners')
var buttonMinus = document.getElementById('brand_minus');

var clone = original.cloneNode(true); 
var count= counts.length;
clone.id = "duplicater" + count;
buttonMinus.id ='brand_minus'+ count;
console.log(count)
original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
});

document.getElementById('brand_minus').addEventListener('click', () => {
});
```

Comment: Когда будете задавать следующий вопрос, постарайтесь привести пример вашего решения (даже если оно не работает). Возможно, вы находились на правильном пути и просто немножко не дошли.

Это поможет другим участникам сообщества не тратить время на анализ вашего кода и попытки понять, что именно вам нужно.

Удачи!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для решения подобных задач в настоящее время проще использовать разного рода библиотеки и фреймворки, позволяющие упростить рутиные операции с DOM. Рекомендую вам ознакомиться, например, с [Vue.js](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html) - этот фреймворк имеет низкий порог входа, и подобные задачи решаются в нём практически на уровне вёрстки шаблона.

Что же касается вашего подхода, то к нему есть ряд претензий, например, используя метод `cloneNode`, вы будет получать действительную копию узла, а значит, если узел содержит поля ввода, то и их значения будут клонированы.

Я бы предложил вам в таком случае создавать и наполнять узел явно.
Да, это лишит вас удобств, присущих вёрстке, но зато будет действительно хорошо работать и даст понимание того, как устроен DOM.

```js
function addBlock(parent) {
    const main = document.createElement("div")
    main.className = "partners"

    const row = document.createElement("div")
    row.className = "row"
    main.appendChild(row)

    const nameLabel = document.createElement("label")
    nameLabel.innerHTML = "Имя"
    row.appendChild(nameLabel)

    const inputTextRow = document.createElement("div")
    inputTextRow.className = "col-lg-6 col-md-9 col-sm-12"
    row.appendChild(inputTextRow)

    const inputText = document.createElement("input")
    inputText.className = "form-control"
    inputTextRow.appendChild(inputText)

    const formGroupRow = document.createElement("div")
    formGroupRow.className = "form-group row"
    main.appendChild(formGroupRow)

    const fileLabel = document.createElement("label")
    fileLabel.innerHTML = "Загрузка фото"
    formGroupRow.appendChild(fileLabel)

    const inputFileRow = document.createElement("div")
    inputFileRow.className = "col-lg-6 col-md-9 col-sm-12"
    formGroupRow.appendChild(inputFileRow)

    const fileForm = document.createElement("form")
    fileForm.enctype  = "multipart/form-data"
    fileForm.method  = "post"
    inputFileRow.appendChild(fileForm)

    const inputFile = document.createElement("input")
    inputFile.className = "form-control"
    inputFile.type = "file"
    fileForm.appendChild(inputFile)

    const formGroupRow2 = document.createElement("div")
    formGroupRow2.className = "form-group row"
    main.appendChild(formGroupRow2)

    const minusButton = document.createElement("button")
    minusButton.className = "btn"
    minusButton.innerHTML = '<span><i class="la la-minus"></i><span>-</span></span>'
    minusButton.onclick = () => {
        parent.removeChild(main)
    }

    formGroupRow2.appendChild(minusButton)

    parent.appendChild(main)
}

document.getElementById("brand_plus").onclick = () => {
    addBlock(document.getElementById("partners_block"))
}

addBlock(document.getElementById("partners_block"))
```

```html
<div class="k-portlet__body" id="partners_block"></div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <button class="but-plus" id="brand_plus">
            <span>
                <i class="la la-plus"></i>
                <span>+</span>
            </span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Такого же поведения, но с сохранением возможности указывать содержание узла в HTML-формате, можно добиться используя такой способ:

```js
function addBlock(parent) {
    const main = document.createElement("div")
    main.className = "partners"
    main.innerHTML = `
        <div class="row">
            <label>Имя</label>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
                <input class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label>Загрузка фото</label>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
                <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                    <input class="form-control" type="file">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <button class="btn">
                <span><i class="la la-minus"></i><span>-</span></span>
            </button>
        </div>`

    main.getElementsByClassName("btn")[0].onclick = () => {
        parent.removeChild(main)
    }

    parent.appendChild(main)
}

document.getElementById("brand_plus").onclick = () => {
    addBlock(document.getElementById("partners_block"))
}

addBlock(document.getElementById("partners_block"))
```

```html
<div class="k-portlet__body" id="partners_block"></div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <button class="but-plus" id="brand_plus">
            <span>
                <i class="la la-plus"></i>
                <span>+</span>
            </span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Хочу отметить, что данный код не является примером безопасного кода: здесь отсутствуют проверки для методов, выполняющих поиск элементов по селектору, а значит, нет гарантий, что данное решение будет корректно отрабатывать во всех случаях.
Чтоб разрешить эту проблему вы должны будете самостоятельно добавить все соответствующие проверки.

И присмотритесь к современным инструментам разработки веб-приложений всё же - многие их них имеют всё необходимое для подобный кейсов "из коробки".

Удачи!